# Creating a hyperlink for a excel sheet: xlsxwriter

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

Is it possible to create a hyperlink for a specific sheet of an excel file?

I want to open a sheet on the click of a cell which is on another sheet of the same excel file. For example, if someone clicks on 'A1' cell which is in the sheet2 the sheet1 will be opened and both the sheets are in the abc.xlsx file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this with the XlsxWriter Worksheet `write_url()` method using the `internal:` URI. See the XlsxWriter docs on [write_url()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-url).

Comment: I am doing this :
worksheet.write_url('A1', "internal: 'sheet name'") 
and getting error that invalid rang.

Comment: Thanaks it worked ! 
Only thing we have to do is we need to give the path of a complete cell of the sheet instead of only to the sheet path.

Answer (score 2):

To put a "Friendly Name" in the hyperlink use the string argument of `write_url()` method. For example, I did the following after setting the variable `sheet_name`, which in this case is both the name of the sheet to link to and the friendly name:

```
write_url(row, col, f"internal:'{sheet_name}'!A1", string=sheet_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

I was unable to get this to work using the "write_url(A1, "internal:'sheet name'!A2")" form.  Can someone provide some guidance on this?

I **was** able to successfully add hyperlinks to internal cells using the form:

write('A1', '=HYPERLINK(CELL("address", 'sheet name'!A2), "Friendly Name")

NOTE: the word 'address' is literal/not a generic reference, and, the quotes need to be specified as shown (i.e., single quotes for a multi-word sheet name, and double quotes for the word 'address' and the 'Friendly Name'...

Comment: “Can someone provide some guidance on this?” Rather than ask a question in answer you should ask a new question with some sample code that demonstrates the problem.